# How to set Custom Header for all xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to add customheaders to all ajax requests . I'm able to do this using the following code .Except in one case.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
        if (!options.beforeSend) {
            options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', '1234');
            }
        }
});
```

Suppose if we are putting beforesend in $.ajax request , the above prefilter is not firing (example below). Can you please tell me how can I acheive it by keeping both?. Is there any way can we add header to xmlHttpRequest so that we can use for all ajax requests that are going from application?

```
 $("#AdvancedserchClick").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: getUrlWithTabId("@Url.Action("AdvancedSearch",   "AdvancedSearch")"),
            beforeSend: function () {
                Load.show();
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#advancedsearch").modal('show');
                $("#advancedsearch").html(result);
            },
            complete: function () {
                Load.hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: But if you just remove the check `if (!options.beforeSend)` both will be called...

Comment: But local beforesend call is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the below code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```

Or you can use pre-filter would be an easy way of accomplishing this but this way all requests will get the custom header, unless the specific request overrides the beforeSend option.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
    if ( !options.beforeSend) {
        options.beforeSend = function (xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('CUSTOM-HEADER-KEY', 'CUSTOM-HEADER-VALUE');
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, xhr ) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', '1234');
 });
```

Docs say :

```
 jQuery.ajaxPrefilter( [dataTypes ], handler ) 

 Description: Handle custom Ajax options or modify existing options before   
 each request is sent and before they are processed by $.ajax()
```